# changing html data attributes in a list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, list, tone.js

I'm making a web based synth/piano and I'm trying to create a pitch shift function where pressing a button updates the 'data-note' attributes to different values. This is the code I have:

```
<body>

  
    
    <button onclick="Sin1()" type="button">Sine1</button><br>
    <button onclick="Square1()" type="button">Square1</button><br>
    <button onclick="Triangle1()" type="button">Triangle1</button><br>
    <button onclick="Sawtooth1()" type="button">Sawtooth1</button><br>
    <button onclick="Sin2()" type="button">Sine2</button><br>
    <button onclick="Square2()" type="button">Square2</button><br>
    <button onclick="Triangle2()" type="button">Triangle2</button><br>
    <button onclick="Sawtooth2()" type="button">Sawtooth2</button><br>
    <button onclick="Sin3()" type="button">Sine3</button><br>
    <button onclick="Square3()" type="button">Square3</button><br>
    <button onclick="Triangle3()" type="button">Triangle3</button><br>
    <button onclick="Sawtooth3()" type="button">Sawtooth3</button><br>
    <button onclick="OctaveShift()" type="button">OctaveShift</button><br>




<ul id="piano">

    <li data-note = "C3" class="key">
    <div data-note="C#3" class="black-key">C#3</div>
    C3
  </li>
  <li data-note="D3" class="key">
    <div data-note="D#3" class="black-key">D#3</div>
    D3
  </li>
  <li data-note="E3" class="key">
    E
  </li>
  <li data-note="F3" class="key">
    <div data-note="F#3" class="black-key">F#3</div>
    F
  </li>
  <li data-note="G3" class="key">
    <div data-note="G#3" class="black-key">G#3</div>
    G3
  </li>
  <li data-note="A3" class="key">
    <div data-note="A#3" class="black-key">A#3</div>
    A3
  </li>
  <li data-note="B3" class="key">
    B3
    </li>
  <li data-note="C4" class="key">
    <div data-note="C#4" class="black-key">C#4</div>
    C4
  </li>
  <li data-note="D4" class="key">
    <div data-note="D#4" class="black-key">D#4</div>
    D4
  </li>
  <li data-note="E4" class="key">
    E4
  </li>
  <li data-note="F4" class="key">
    <div data-note="F#4" class="black-key">F#4</div>
    F4
  </li>
  <li data-note="G4" class="key">
    <div data-note="G#4" class="black-key">G#4</div>
    G4
  </li>
  <li data-note="A4" class="key">
    <div data-note="A#4" class="black-key">A#4</div>
    A4
  </li>
  <li data-note="B4" class="key">
    B4
  </li>

</ul>

<script src="http://unpkg.com/tone"></script>

<script>

function OctaveShift(){
  let changednote = piano.getAttribute("data-note")
  piano.setAttribute("data-note","C5" )
  console.log((changednote))
};

const gainnode1 = new Tone.Gain();
gainnode1.toDestination();
console.log(gainnode1);

const gainnode2 = new Tone.Gain();
gainnode2.toDestination();

const gainnode3 = new Tone.Gain();
gainnode3.toDestination();

const synth1 = new Tone.Synth();
synth1.oscillator.type = "sine";
synth1.connect(gainnode1);

const synth2 = new Tone.Synth();
synth2.oscillator.type = "sine";
synth2.connect(gainnode2);

const synth3 = new Tone.Synth();
synth3.oscillator.type = "sine";
synth3.connect(gainnode3);


const piano = document.getElementById("piano");

piano.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
    console.log("synth1fired");
  synth1.triggerAttack(e.target.dataset.note);
});

piano.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
    console.log("synth2fired");
  synth2.triggerAttack(e.target.dataset.note);
});

piano.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
    console.log("synth3fired");
  synth3.triggerAttack(e.target.dataset.note);
});

piano.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
  synth1.triggerRelease();
});

piano.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
  synth2.triggerRelease();
});

piano.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
  synth3.triggerRelease();
});


function Sin1(){
synth1.oscillator.type= 'sine';
console.log(synth1);
}
function Square1(){
synth1.oscillator.type= 'square';
console.log(synth1);
}
function Triangle1(){
synth1.oscillator.type= 'triangle';
console.log(synth1);
}
function Sawtooth1(){
synth1.oscillator.type= 'sawtooth';
console.log(synth1);
}
function Sin2(){
synth2.oscillator.type= 'sine';
console.log(synth2);
}
function Square2(){
synth2.oscillator.type= 'square';
console.log(synth2);
}
function Triangle2(){
synth2.oscillator.type= 'triangle';
console.log(synth2);
}
function Sawtooth2(){
synth2.oscillator.type= 'sawtooth';
console.log(synth2)
}
function Sin3(){
synth2.oscillator.type= 'sine';
console.log(synth2);
}
function Square3(){
synth2.oscillator.type= 'square';
console.log(synth2);
}
function Triangle3(){
synth2.oscillator.type= 'triangle';
console.log(synth2);
}
function Sawtooth3(){
synth2.oscillator.type= 'sawtooth';
console.log(synth2)
}

</script>



</body>
```

I expected this to update all the data-note values to C5, but when I after pressing the octave shift and then hitting the keys, there is no change in pitch. I think this is because the piano id contains a list but I am unsure how to reference the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change all `data-note` values by clicking `octave-shift`, you've to grab all elements that have the attribute `data-note` then loop through them to set a new value of that attribute.

```js
const datanotes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-note]');

function OctaveShift() {
    datanotes.forEach(function (datanote) {
        datanote.setAttribute("data-note", "C5");
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much it worked! If I wanted to change each data note to a different note instead, would setting up a loop be enough?